# Load Bootstrap accordion before ng-src image

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm using Bootstrap accordion and inside each panel I'm listing employees using `ng-repeat` and for each employee I'm loading an image using `ng-src`. When a panel is clicked, the employee's image loads for some time, disappears then opens in the accordion. How can I make the employee's image load after the accordion opens completely.

This is a snippet listing the employees:

```
<div id="newly-on-board" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul style="list-style: none;">
            <li>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-2">
                        <b>Name</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3">
                        <b>Job Title</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3">
                        <b>Image</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4">
                        <b>Description</b>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li data-ng-repeat="employee in EmployeesToDisplay">
                <a style="cursor: pointer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-2">
                            {{employee.Name}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3">
                            {{employee.JobTitle}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-circle center-block" width="200" height="200" data-ng-src="{{getImageUrl(employee)}}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4">
                            {{employee.Description}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding ng-cloak to your accordion. ng-cloak waits for the scope variable to be ready before injecting the DOM element & hence will wait till the entire data is ready before displaying any of the elements. A link to the directive is below : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak